# CallBack from MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, callback, media-player

I have a MediaPlayer and an audio file, which I need to play, also I have an ArrayList with the certain seconds of this audio file, on this seconds while audio is playing, I need to switch pages in the ViewPager. How to get a CallBack from the MediaPlayer in these certain moments of the time? or maybe you will recommend some other way how is possible to do it.

What I have right now is the method, where I use CountDownTimer, which change pages in ViewPager, but it works wrong and it doesn't take into the account fact that an audio track can be stop and then resume.

```
 public void startPlayingLabels() {

        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            String mFileName = CameraFragment.mAudioFolder + "/" + ViewActivity.parentName + ".3gp";
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();

            for (int i=0; i<zeroLabelPosition.size()-1; i++) {

                final int finalI = i;
                new CountDownTimer(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt((String) zeroTime.get(finalI + 1)) - Integer.parseInt((String) zeroTime.get(finalI)))), 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(zeroLabelPosition.get(finalI))));
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add more code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android madiaplayer does not have any timeline update, thats why you can write your own, or you can use something like this.

```
CountDownTimer timer;
int timeStampIterator;
int[] timeStamp = new int[5]; // your own time stamps when view must be switched

void play() { 
   mPlayer.start();
    timer = new CountDownTimer(mPlayer.getDuration() - mPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int timeSpends = mPlayer.getDuration() - mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            if (timeSpends == timeStamp[timeStampIterator]) {
                //switchToNExtSlide();
                timeStampIterator++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
}

void pause() {
    mPlayer.pause();
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
}

void stop() {
    mPlayer.stop();
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
    timeStampIterator = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use handler for it like following

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

       Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startPlayProgressUpdater();// change hear page for view pager, because it call after every 1 second
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
```